# Can I conduct a z-test on the difference in proportions taken across variables rather than within?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, survey

[image]I have 2 dichotomous variables, but I want to compare the proportions of only one group from each of the variables within a third, dichotomous response variable.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data itself to make this more clear?

Comment: Variables were taken from a large national survey. I have two dichotomous variables- Full-time/part-time and self-employed with employees/self-employed without employees. I generated crosstabs with each of them to see their proportions within another variable. What I want to do is to conduct a z-test on the proportion of full-timers and the proportion of self-employed without employees within the third variable. I hope that helps.

Comment: Please edit additional information into your question

Comment: So can I run a z-test for "full-time" proportion (0.277) vs "on own, with partner(s) but no employees" proportion (0.365)?

Comment: Yes, but you need to confirm if survey sampling methods were used. If so, you do not have a simple random sample and test procedures will not give correct estimates.

Comment: The data's been taken from a large representative, national survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal approximation of the binomial is a potential solution. You can take the difference in proportions and compare as a single sample z-test to a reference value of `0`. For the difference in proportions, the 95% confidence interval for the difference is `-11.5` to `-0.06` and the p-value for the difference is `1.977e-11`.

However, if businesses can be viewed as having one of two states: `in-work benefits` or `other benefits`, one can conceive of your data as two groups with 2 possible outcomes as:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & \text{In-work benefits} & \text{Other benefits} \\
\hline
\text{Full-time} & 1090 & 2846  \\
\text{On own w/ partners w/o employees} & 659 & 1146  
\end{array}
$$

This table can then be analyzed using a chi-square test. The p-value is also `1.977e-11`.

Your data are more naturally trials between two groups and I favor treatment as counts. However, the results are identical.

This assumes that the values were obtained from a simple random sample. If there was a survey with a sampling design, the answer to your question is “no” a z-test will not work and survey techniques are required to obtain the correct estimates.

Comment: I'm aiming to compare the proportion of full-timers with the proportion of "on own, with partner(s) but no employees" who claimed in-work benefits. The reason I'm confused as to whether I can use a two sample z test is that all the examples of this test I came across with compare proportions between the groups within a variable (e.g. gender variable male/female) rather than across them (like in this case). I'm wondering whether a two sample z test would be appropriate in this particular instance.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. Maybe edit your question further if the provided answer is insufficient.

Comment: Can I use a z-test to estimate the statistical significance for the difference in 2 proportions I've incircled on the screenshot?